# What can cause the application to report Undefined symbol __shlinit from a .sl library in HP-UX 11.00?

Tags: c, hp-ux, acc

I am building a .sl library using aCC in HP-UX 11.00. I am able to build it and then link it to the application also successfully.

But, when I execute the exe, it gives the below error

/usr/lib/dld.sl: Unresolved Symbol: __shlinit(code) from mylib.sl

Any pointers towards resolving this problem will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is mylib.sl your library I take it?

Is your library perhaps calling a function called `shlinit()` at any point? If not more probably another library function that your code, or the application code, is calling then goes on to call `shlinit()`.

`shlinit()`is obviously implemented in another library that you do not have installed or is not installed in the correct place or somewhere your dynamic link path points to.

You need to find which library implements that function and ensure it is correctly installed.

A quick Google search gives the following link which may be useful, but now I have to go:

[unresolved symbol: __shlinit during shlload()](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCUQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforums11.itrc.hp.com%2Fservice%2Fforums%2Fquestionanswer.do%3FthreadId%3D132021&rct=j&q=shlinit&ei=cdQmTYbTIcubhQfCg52GAg&usg=AFQjCNFfCkGDt04UEetkmgdvB2BXrTF0xg&cad=rja)